# Can i query GraphQL single responce multiple times by graphQL query?

Tags: graphql

I am creating a BFF app using GraphQL React-Apollo, what I want
1) on a single request whatever data I am getting can I query that data-set again multiple times without sending another request.

let say I am getting

```
[{
   group1:[
     {id:123,name:"abcd"}
     {id:133,name:"sdfg"}
   ],
   group2:[
     {id:1234,name:"abdfcd"}
     {id:1333,name:"sdffgg"}
   ]
   group3:[
     {id:12234,name:"abdffgcd"}
     {id:13333,name:"sdfdgffgg"}
   ]
}]
```

Now I want to fetch group1 data from one component group2 data from another component
so it's possible to call BFF from React 2 times more but not send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your client is a Apollo Client and your BFF is a separate service. If this is correct then yes you can do what you have explained.

While executing any query from Apollo Client you can specify the network policy.
So for the first one your can mark it as "Network only" and for the next two you can do "Cache first".

In this case as soon as your first query is executed, Apollo will cache your data and then for the second query call you will get the data without actually going over the network.